Why is the intersection number equal to the integral over the submanifold?
Let $X$ be a $n$-dimensional compact connected complex manifold and $V$ its connected submanifold of dimension $k$. Let $D_1,\cdots, D_k$ be divisors on $X$.
Each of the line bundles $\mathcal{O}_X\left(D_i\right)$ has a first Chern Chern class
$$
c_1\left(\mathcal{O}_X\left(D_i\right)\right) \in H^2(X ; \mathbf{Z}),
$$
The cup product of these classes is then an element
$$
c_1\left(\mathcal{O}_X\left(D_1\right)\right) \cdot \ldots \cdot c_1\left(\mathcal{O}_X\left(D_k\right)\right) \in H^{2 k}(X ; \mathbf{Z}):
$$
Denoting by $[V] \in H_{2 k}(X ; \mathbf{Z})$ the fundamental class of $V$, cap product leads finally to an integer
$$
\left(c_1\left(\mathcal{O}_X\left(D_1\right)\right) \cdot \ldots \cdot c_1\left(\mathcal{O}_X\left(D_k\right)\right)\right) \cap[V] \in H_0(X ; \mathbf{Z})=\mathbf{Z}
$$
$\left(c_1\left(\mathcal{O}_X\left(D_1\right)\right) \cdot \ldots \cdot c_1\left(\mathcal{O}_X\left(D_k\right)\right)\right) \cap[V]$  is called the intersection number.
In many occasions, I  have heard many individuals assert that  the  intersection number is equal to the integral $\int_V c_1\left(\mathcal{O}_X\left(D_1\right)\right) \wedge \ldots \wedge c_1\left(\mathcal{O}_X\left(D_k\right)\right)$. (Here we use the notation $c_1\left(\mathcal{O}_X\left(D_i\right)\right)$ to denote   any differential form that serves as a representative of this  class). I also think this formula is correct and I think many references have used this formula implicitly.

Question: 1, How to rigorously prove this formula:
$$\left(c_1\left(\mathcal{O}_X\left(D_1\right)\right) \cdot \ldots
> \cdot c_1\left(\mathcal{O}_X\left(D_k\right)\right)\right) \cap[V]=
> \int_V c_1\left(\mathcal{O}_X\left(D_1\right)\right) \wedge \ldots
> \wedge c_1\left(\mathcal{O}_X\left(D_k\right)\right) ?$$
2, If we replace the submanifold $V$ by a singular subvariety, does
this formula also hold?


Does this help?

Yes, this is a very special case of a general result in the linked question.
